# I am on Ubuntu. How do I expand last partition in GParted?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, gparted

So my dilemma is that my Ubuntu installation is on the last partition. Here is a screenshot of GParted.

[image: GParted screenshot]

Also on a hdd. Not sure if it makes a difference.

Comment: The little key icons show your mounted partitions. So you cannot edit those partitions. Use live installer as per answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won’t be able to resize the partition that you are current running in - it appears here that you’re booted into the Linux install that’s running on /dev/sda5?  If that’s the case, you can boot a liveCD or a USB installer, so that all of the partitions on /dev/sda are unmounted.  Once unmounted and booted from a liveCD you should be able to extend/resize those partitions into the unallocated space.

Comment: Ok I will try it.

Comment: If that works, please accept/upvote accordingly.  If not, let us know where you got stuck.